# "cannot import name smbserver" when using impacket with smbrelayx.py

Tags: python, impacket

I know this is not an actual info-sec question, but I am having problems with getting the smbrealyx.py module to work. For some reason I get the following error when I try to execute the aforementioned python program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "smbrelayx.py", line 43, in <module>
 from impacket import smbserver, smb, ntlm, dcerpc, version
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/impacket/smbserver.py", line 18, in <module>
  from impacket import smbserver, version
ImportError: cannot import name smbserver
```

I am not familiar with python programming and I was hoping someone could help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an old `impacket` version installed and you are using a newer version of `smbrelayx.py`.

First of it'd be great to know what version you have. You can easily do that by typing inside a Python interpreter the following:

```
from impacket import version
print version.BANNER
```

Assuming you have an old version, first of all it'd be great to remove the existing version. Depending on your Unix distro it might be just as easy as to remove the `python-impacket` package, or you can manually remove the library files by getting to know where those files are located:

```
import impacket
print impacket.__file__
```

That will give you the path where the library is installed. I'd suggest to remove the entire directory.

Now that your system is clean, you have two options:

1. Install a stable version: Grab the latest stable version from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/impacket). Uncompress it in a temp directory and then run:

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

   That will install the libraries and example scripts (e.g. `smbrelayx.py`)
2. Install the development version: You will need to `git clone` the development version first by running:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/CoreSecurity/impacket
   ```

   Once the repo is cloned, inside the `impacket` directory type:

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

   That will install the libraries and example scripts (e.g. `smbrelayx.py`)